# Missing 'libseccomp2:amd64' and other on Ubuntu Server 18.04 on RaspberryPi

Tags: server, docker, raspberrypi

I'm trying to install docker on Ubuntu Server 18.04 on RaspberryPi. I'm following the instructions on Docker's site. I've stucked on step `sudo apt-get install docker-ce:amd64 docker-ce-cli:amd64 containerd.io:amd64`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 containerd.io:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.14) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libseccomp2:amd64 (>= 2.4.0) but it is not installable
 docker-ce:amd64 : Depends: libseccomp2:amd64 (>= 2.3.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.8) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (>= 2:1.02.97) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libsystemd0:amd64 but it is not installable
                   Recommends: aufs-tools:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: cgroupfs-mount:amd64 or
                               cgroup-lite:amd64 but it is not installable
                   Recommends: pigz:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libltdl7:amd64 but it is not installable
                   Recommends: apparmor:amd64 but it is not installable
 docker-ce-cli:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried adding some new repositories from similar questions. Without any luck.

My current `source.list`

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic main restricted
deb [arch=amd64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates main restricted
deb [arch=amd64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security main restricted
deb [arch=amd64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable

# custom
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe multiverse

deb [arch=amd64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

deb [arch=amd64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

## My question is

Which repository should I add or what I'm doing wrong?
To be exact I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with `18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1041-raspi2 aarch64)`

Comment: RaspberryPi is not amd64. So it is absolutely expected behavior. You can check it by running `arch` command on RaspberryPi. The [manual](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) mention ARM architectures, so you can simply use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG: Just when I wrote `aarch64`. I was trying to install docker for wrong architecture. `AMD64` instead of `arm64/aarch64`. In Docker's instruction `amd64` is preselected. I haven't not noticed it at first.

## To summarize:

In step 4 it's important to chose a correct architecture. For me it is `arm64`.